# st terminal not respecting my shortcut setting

Tags: suckless-terminal

I have the clipboard patch installed, and the following lines in my `config.h`

```
#define MODKEY Mod1Mask
#define TERMMOD (Mod1Mask|ShiftMask)
```

and

```
{ ShiftMask,            XK_Insert,      clippaste,      {.i =  0} },
{ TERMMOD,               XK_c,           clipcopy,       {.i =  0} },
{ TERMMOD,               XK_v,           clippaste,      {.i =  0} },
{ MODKEY,               XK_p,           selpaste,       {.i =  0} },
```

Interestingly `Shift+Insert` and mid-click on mouse let me paste from clipboard but the combination using `TERMMOD` and `MODKEY` from above don't. Other shortcuts using `TERMMOD` and `MODKEY` (e.g. zoom in/out, printscreen, scrolling) work. I tried to use other combinations like `Ctrl+Shift+c/v` but no joy. The same combination would work on xterm, urxvt and alacritty (I haven't exhaustively tested other emulators yet).

Can any one please shed some light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [default keybindings in the `st` source](https://git.suckless.org/st/file/config.def.h.html#l177), the binding uses `XK_V` (note capital).

```
    { TERMMOD,              XK_C,           clipcopy,       {.i =  0} },
    { TERMMOD,              XK_V,           clippaste,      {.i =  0} },
    { TERMMOD,              XK_Y,           selpaste,       {.i =  0} },
```

Try changing your lowercase `XK_v` back to that (while keeping your new value of `TERMMOD`).

## Explanation

`XK_v` and `XK_V` are defined as 0x76 and 0x56 in the X11 include file `keysymdef.h`.  They are considered different keypresses.  You can test this with the `xev` tool:

Without <kbd>Shift</kbd>:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 47, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x4cf, subw 0x0, time 433723403, (134,121), root:(1235,171),
    state 0x0, keycode 55 (keysym 0x76, v), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (76) "v"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (76) "v"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

With <kbd>Shift</kbd> held down, the same `keycode` results in a different `keysym`.

```
KeyPress event, serial 47, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x4cf, subw 0x0, time 433724571, (134,121), root:(1235,171),
    state 0x1, keycode 55 (keysym 0x56, V), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (56) "V"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (56) "V"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

When you use `XK_v` in conjunction with `TERMMOD`, and `TERMMOD` contains `ShiftMask`, you are telling `st` you want to paste when a lowercase <kbd>v</kbd> is received while <kbd>Shift</kbd> is down.  But when you're holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, the X server sends an uppercase <kbd>V</kbd> key instead.  That's not what `st` was looking for, so it does nothing.